# check if string is image

Tags: php, image

There is an image in string format, outputting that string with some mime type headers would be enough to render it on a page, how to check if that string is an image?

Comment: By "string format" do you mean base64?  If so you should look into magic number libraries.  (The most common of these is simply called "magic.")

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"An image resource will be returned on success. FALSE is returned if the image type is unsupported, the data is not in a recognised format, or the image is corrupt and cannot be loaded."

Example:

```
<?php
$data = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAASCAMAAAB/2U7WAAAABl'
       . 'BMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAASUlEQVR4XqWQUQoAIAxC2/0vXZDr'
       . 'EX4IJTRkb7lobNUStXsB0jIXIAMSsQnWlsV+wULF4Avk9fLq2r'
       . '8a5HSE35Q3eO2XP1A1wQkZSgETvDtKdQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';
$data = base64_decode($data);

$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
if ($im !== false) {
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
}
else {
    echo 'An error occurred.';
}
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php

Comment: You need to suppress errors using '@' or else you are doomed for that `imagecreatefromstring()` .

Comment: @ngen Any way to avoid getting doomed and at the same time avoid using @?

Comment: @YuriKolovsky You can't . Since you are trying to load a string into a function which is expecting an image.   It will fail  1) if the image data is corrupt . 2) if it's not an image.